# line breaks within tikz-qtree

Tags: tikz-qtree

I am trying to force a line break within leaves of my tree (using tikz-qtree), and I found two previous questions about this but none of the answers provided worked for me. Here is my example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\tikzset{baseline,every tree node/.style={align=center,anchor=north}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree [.S [.NP {the\\man} ] [.VP [.V {went} ] [.AdvP {away} ] ] ]
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

It doesn't seem to matter whether I put the `\tikzset` command within the tikzpicture environment or in the preamble, or whether I include 'baseline' in the `\tikzset` command. The error message I keep getting is this:

> Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/align' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

Comment: You can highlight code in your post using back-ticks. To highlight code-blocks, either indent them by four spaces or use the `{}` on the gui.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! When I run the code under TeXLive 2016, I don't get any errors, and the line break looks ok. Maybe you use an old version? My `tikz` is from `2015/08/07 v3.0.1a`, and my `tikz-qtree.tex` (this is what is finally loaded) has version `1.2, 20 Apr 2012` (for the version information you have to look into the file `tikz-qtree.tex`, it is not written to the `log` file).

Comment: The error message just means that in your version of `tikz` and `qtree`, the option `align` does not exist.

Comment: Thank you. I just checked, and that is my version of tikz-qtree too. I tried downloading the latest version of tikz and pgf, and I still get the same error. Could the problem be with TeXShop?

Comment: No the problem has nothing to do with TeXShop which is an editor.  It's more likely that you have a local version of tikz that is overriding the one you found. What does `kpsewhich tikz.sty` return (typed into s terminal window). Also you can use `\pgfversion` in a document to display the actual version. Do it in a document that actually compiles.

Comment: Also, don't download the latest version of Ti*k*Z/PGF. If you need to update, update your installation of TeX rather than trying to update individual packages piecemeal. That way, you stand a fighting chance things might get along OK together.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I dragged the folder containing all my style files to my desktop (out of the Library/texmf folder) and downloaded MacTeX anew, and now it works. I am confused though about "where" everything is. When I look in my ~/Library folder there is no obvious location for style files. I used to have everything in Library/texmf/tex/latex and then a subfolder called "misha's".

Comment: Aren't they on your desktop where you left them?

Comment: Yes, sorry. The old folder is where I left it. But I moved it out because that was what was making the file with tikz-qtree fail to compile. What I'm confused about is where the new packages are--when I downloaded the new MacTeX, where would it have put everything? Sorry if I am not asking this clearly.

Comment: @Misha If you want to get somebody's attention, you need to ping them with `@`. (Unless they posted the question - so I don't really need to ping you as you'll be pinged anyhow.) The default installation location is `/usr/local/texlive/2016`. For MacTeX, some files will also be installed in other places - probably `/Library/<something-something>` but I don't have current MacTeX to check. But the packages etc. will all be under `/usr/local` unless you changed the location when installing.